# ReSharper C++ support for single-underscore keywords

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using ReSharper with a large legacy C/C++ project. This project happens to use single-underscore versions of ANSI keywords such as _int64 and _int32. ReSharper doesn't recognize these types, so I have thousands of red squiggles.

For example, on a line such as:

```
unsigned _int64 x;
```

When I hover over the resulting red squiggle I see:

```
"(Local variable) unsigned _int64"

"Local variable '_int64' is never used"

"Expected ';'"
```

If I change it to a double underscore __int64 then everything is fine, but I'd rather not make thousands of changes just to make ReSharper happy.

Microsoft supports both the single and double underscore versions of the keywords according to [their documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx):

> For backward compatibility, single-underscore versions of all the
>   double-underscored keywords except __except, __finally, __leave, and
>   __try are supported.

Is there any way to enable support for the single-underscore types in ReSharper C++?

Comment: Why not just change it, once and for all, to use the standard type names - like `int64_t`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yeah, it may come to that, but right now I'm reviewing this code, and would like to keep the scope of code changes to functional and bug fixes only so that they can easily be seen with a diff search.

Comment: multiple individual commits are always an option ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the definitive answer back from JetBrains:

> There's no way to enable it at the moment, but we'll soon add support
>   for single-underscore keywords (hopefully in 2017.1 or a patch
>   release). You can follow
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-18673 to receive updates.